# Getting the error 'unresolved reference: Result' whenever I add the 'reqwest' package. Code compiles but IDE shows as error

Tags: rust, reqwest

When I add the reqwest dependency `reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["json"] }` I start getting an `unresolved reference: Result` for any Result object `fn foo() -> Result<>{}` in main.rs. If I remove the "reqwest" dependency, the errors disappear. Any reasons this could happen? I'm using rustc 1.67.0-nightly.

Edit: The code compiles properly, but the code editor says 'unresolved reference: Result' and 'Result' is hilighted in red. So maybe an issue with the IDE? I'm using Pycharm.

> main.rs

```
use std::error::Error;


fn foo() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>{Ok(())}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

> cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "AoC2021"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["json"] }
```

Comment: A reproducible example please?

Comment: Your code gives "error[E0308]: mismatched types" not a reference error cause you don't return an `Ok(())` or `Err` variant. After I add that, it shows a few warnings about a bad crate name & an unused function but still no reference error.

Comment: @cafce25 I edited my question and returned Ok(()). Seems to be an IDE issue maybe. I'm able to compile the code now but the IDE still shows it as an error for some reason

Comment: Is the `rust-analyzer` (or what you use instead) you use from your IDE up to date with the rust version you're compiling with?